# How to locate the grammar file in sphinx java

Tags: java, xml, swing, speech-to-text, speech-synthesis

i am making a speech to text application using sphinx
But the location of the grammar file in the config.xml is not correct or i am not getting the right path.

```
<!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- The Grammar  configuration                               -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->

    <component name="jsgfGrammar" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.jsapi.JSGFGrammar">
        <property name="dictionary" value="dictionary"/>
        <property name="grammarLocation" 
             value="resource:/com/stt/project/" />
        <property name="grammarName" value="Grammer"/>
    <property name="logMath" value="logMath"/>
    </component>
```

The structure of the files are in the image here : 
[File Hiererchy of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6s0h.jpg)

> This problem has been resolved by using the cmusphinx api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at CMUSphinks api for Speech-to-text as it seems all the implementations at the moment are for the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to pick one of the [implementations](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jsapifaq-135248.html#implementation)?

*Update based on discussion:*
You can look at [Sphinks4](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4) for Speech-to-text as it seems all the implementations at the moment are for the other way around.

Comment: That means javax.speech is no longer available?

Comment: Nope, it means it is an API. That is just a specification, and various teams made various implementations for that. See the linked page for "The Java Speech API (JSAPI) is not part of the JDK and Sun does not ship an implementation of JSAPI."

Comment: i have checked the site but i think all of the implementations are for the TEXT-TO-SPEECH but i need speech to text

Comment: Hmm, thats quite possible. Since the JSAPI looks pretty abandoned anyway, maybe you can look at http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4 for a more recent and maintained library. Never tried myself, it just looks newer.